# Inter Package communication in Java?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a code which is half generated by Netbeans IDE through selecting the containers and controllers.  Within the project I have a couple of packages which should work together and be able to see one another's variables and methods.  In one of the packages I have a JList item which needs to be populated when the JPanel from this other package receives the user input.  However for some reason this link is not possible!

PACKAGE LMB ------------------------------------------------

```
//This is the main class initializing the LMBView class
 public class IDAApp extends SingleFrameApplication {

     @Override
     protected void startup() {
        show(new LMBView(this));
    }
 }


 public class LMBView extends FrameView {

     public javax.swing.JList jList_PortalList;

     private void initComponents() {
          jList_PortalList = new javax.swing.JList();
              .
              .
              .
     }
```

PACKAGE LMB.resources---------------------------------------

```
 LMB.LMBView.jList_PortalList  // DOES NOT WORK OR LINKS TO THE CALLING OBJECT
```

This is the error message shown

```
 non-static variables jList_PortalList cannot be referenced from a static context
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to access to an non static attribute you need a reference of LMBView object. In the other hand you can declare the attribute as static (but this isn't a best practice)

```
public static javax.swing.JList jList_PortalList;
```

If you want to access to the attribute trough a reference you mus do something as follows:

```
// In the main class
public static void main (String args []) {
    LMBView lmb = new  LMBView();
    //Code for show th JFrame
    AnotherClass aclass = new AnotherClass();
    aclass.setLMBView(lmb);
    // Other code
}
```

In your AnotherClass (can be in any package):

```
public class AnotherClass {
    LMBView lmb;

    public void setLMBView(LMBView lmb) {
        this.lmb = lmb;
    }

    //Now for get the value in some method
    public void doStuff() {
        lmb.jList_PortalList.getWherever(); // Replace getWherever with a valid method
    }
}
```

Comment: But this is an auto-generated area in Netbeans and does not allow me to change it.

Comment: And the jList_PortalList is already initialized in LMB package.  This wouldn't even be a static call as far as I know!

Comment: Isn't there a way to access the LMBView instance through import or any other means??!  I need to grab the already instantiated instance of LMBView and be able to update it's parameters!

Comment: @Sam: Find the piece of code which creates the instance, and make sure it propagates the information appropriately. While you *could* take a shortcut and make the assumption that there'll only ever be a single instance of the class (e.g. by making the constructor assign `this` to a static variable) I would *strongly* advise you not to.

Answer (score 0):

with `LMB.LMBView.jList_PortalList` you are trying to access a non-static variable through a static call.  A static call is when you are referencing the name of the class and not an instance of the class.

Therefore, the most plausible solution would be to have a reference of the `LMBView` object and pass this object as a parameter to the jPanel from which you are trying to call the method.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
LMB.LMBView.jList_PortalList
```

is trying to access that variable as if it were static, when it's actually an *instance* variable. You can only access it for a particular *instance*, e.g.

```
LMB.LMBView view = ...;
JList list = view.jList_PortalList;
```

This has nothing to do with packages - you need to understand the difference between static and instance members. It sounds like this *shouldn't* be a static variable, and you should just make sure that the code which needs to access the view has a reference to the relevant instance of `LMBView`.

As a separate matter, public variables are generally a very bad idea - the fields are an implementation detail; you should decide the API to your class in terms of constructors and methods.

Comment: As you can see the jList_PortalList is already instantiated in the LMBView class and is running as part of the main application.  Now my challenge is how would it be possible to grab the instance of this already running jList_PortalList object and update it with elements acquired from this other class located under LMB.resources package?!

Comment: @Sam: I replied to your comment in another answer. It's the instance of `LMBView` that you need to get access to - whatever creates the `LMBView` needs to make it available to whatever cares about it. We can't really help you with that as we don't know the rest of how your application hangs together - but understanding this (the fact that you can't get at instance members without an instance to refer to) is a fundamental part of working with Java. Don't take any shortcuts with this - work out how the information should flow through your system.